# Windows boot manager was destroyed after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub

I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 in Lenovo G50 which runs on Pentium processor. The system already had Windows 8 (manually installed). I separated 50 GB from a partition and turned off Fast boot and set secured boot off and turned boot options to legacy mode. I tried installing Ubuntu , but the separated partition was mentioned as unusable. Then i separated 50 GB from C: partition and tried again. It got installed finally. 
Now when i boot , I dont see the grub . It directly goes into ubuntu. I also tried in boot menu , the windows boot manager is missing. I used commands in Ubuntu to see the possible OS in the system. It didn't list windows in any partition.

What should i do to bring Windows boot back and how to set the grub back? I am sure that Ubuntu didnt destroy Windows, but only the boot file. How to put back the boot alone ?

Comment: You shouldn't have "turned boot options to legacy mode" to install Ubuntu if your Windows is installed in UEFI mode. When you install Ubuntu (hence grub) in legacy mode, grub (i368-pc) will not be able to boot the EFI binaries of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have installed two different OS on two different modes of BIOS (Legacy or UEFI).
Since you have mentioned that you changed the boot option to **Legacy** and then installed Ubuntu , this is the main reason for non-appearance of **GRUB**. I mean to say you have installed Windows in UEFI mode and Ubuntu in Legacy mode , where the GRUB cannot find the **Windows Boot Loader** installed in **UEFI**. So now to boot into Windows changing the boot option to UEFI can be useful.

***To bring back the GRUB I suggest you to remove Ubuntu installed in Legacy mode and reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode.***